# UK flight paths

Tags: data-request, geospatial, uk

There seems to be some data for the US, but is there any vector data for UK flight paths?

The best case scenario is to obtain separate lines/polygons for different altitudes (I only need 0-1000m). 1 years worth of records should do the trick.

---- Update ----

I found this (still not optimal data): http://openflights.org/data.html
If you scroll down you can download global flight paths in the following format:

```
Airline 2-letter (IATA) or 3-letter (ICAO) code of the airline.
Airline ID  Unique OpenFlights identifier for airline (see Airline).
Source airport  3-letter (IATA) or 4-letter (ICAO) code of the source airport.
Source airport ID   Unique OpenFlights identifier for source airport
Destination airport 3-letter (IATA) or 4-letter (ICAO) code of the destination airport.
Destination airport ID  Unique OpenFlights identifier for destination airport
Codeshare   "Y" if this flight is a codeshare (that is, not operated by Airline, but another carrier), empty otherwise.
Stops   Number of stops on this flight ("0" for direct)
Equipment   3-letter codes for plane type(s) generally used on this flight, separated by spaces
```

Sample data:

```
BA,1355,SIN,3316,LHR,507,,0,744 777
BA,1355,SIN,3316,MEL,3339,Y,0,744
TOM,5013,ACE,1055,BFS,465,,0,320
```

So how do I get that data format into QGIS without coordinate data?

Comment: You'd need to find a file with airport code and location in it and then do a join

Comment: Have you  had a look at https://www.xcsoar.org/discover/ ?

Comment: *"There seems to be some data for the US..."* Can you add a link?